# Select all records that were created on a given day N months ago

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table `orders`:

```
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
| id  |  price  |         created_at      |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
|  1  |  16.50  | 2017-02-28 12:52:00.824 |
|  2  |  22.00  | 2017-10-03 15:12:39.107 |
|  3  |  50.00  | 2017-12-03 12:54:42.658 |
|  4  |  12.00  | 2018-01-02 07:21:47.808 |
|  .  |   .     |             .           |
|  .  |   .     |             .           |
|  .  |   .     |             .           |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
```

and current date:

```
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-01-03 10:33:14 |
+---------------------+
```

I'd like to select **all records that were created on current day any months ago**. So for above data my query should return:

```
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
| id  |  price  |         created_at      |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
|  2  |  22.00  | 2017-10-03 15:12:39.107 |
|  3  |  50.00  | 2017-12-03 12:54:42.658 |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+
```

But there are some **edge cases** for the last day of month:

- if it's 31-days month, it's trivial
- if it's 30-days month, the query should return all records created on 30th and 31st day of month
- if it's February in a leap year, the query should return all records created on 29th, 30th and 31st day of month
- if it's February in a normal year, the query should return all records created on 28th, 29th, 30th and 31st day of month

What I have tried is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
JOIN (
  SELECT id, PERIOD_DIFF(
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y%m"),
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y%m")
  ) AS diff
  FROM orders
) AS periods
ON orders.id = periods.id
WHERE DATEDIFF(created_at + INTERVAL diff MONTH, NOW()) = 0;
```

But it doesn't cover the edge cases and I believe there is a *smarter way* (maybe without a subquery) to achieve the expected results.

---

**EDIT:**
To give you more context - what I need is a kind of a loop. I have a `cron job` scheduled to run once a day at midnight. This job should select all `ids` of `orders` that were created on this day any months ago and then refresh some other data associated with those `ids`. The important part is to refresh this data exactly once every month - that's why the last day of months is so crucial.

For example, given following creation dates:

```
DATES = [
  2015-05-30, 2016-02-29, 2016-10-03,
  2016-12-31, 2017-05-28, 2018-01-03
]

+---------------+------------------------------------+
|     NOW()     |         SHOULD BE INCLUDED         |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
|  2018-01-03   | 2016-10-03, 2018-01-03             |
|  2018-02-28   | 2016-02-29, 2016-12-31, 2017-05-28 |
|  2018-04-30   | 2015-05-30, 2016-12-31             |
|  2018-10-31   | 2016-12-31                         |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What happens if today be the 31st of March, and you request for orders one month ago?  February has no 31st day.

Comment: In this case it should not return any records from February.

Comment: @Walerian, are you sure that the behaviour of ignoring the "31st Feb" is desired? I daresay I've yet to come across a report based on the logic of "this day of the month, X months ago" that is useful and robust, precisely because months have a ragged number of days that confounds the situation. This sort of date arithmetic is best implemented with a date table incidentally - then selecting for the 31st Feb will naturally produce a null value.

Comment: @Steve Returning `null` value for 31st Feb is not a problem. The most important thing is to include 31st March if today is 28th Feb.

Comment: @Walerian, I gather what you're saying is that "if the base date is the last date of the base month, select all days in the target month from the base day to the month-end day" but what if today is 28th Jan, and it's a leap year? Do you include both 28th and 29th Feb, or only 28th (because 28th Feb is not then the end of the month)? I'd be interested to know the use-case of this algorithm!

Comment: In such a case it should include only 28th Feb. 29th Feb should be included on 29th Jan. I will edit my question to give more context.

Comment: @Steve I've updated the question, you can see more explanation now.

Comment: @Walerian, that does give more context. Can I suggest, if this is a batch job that runs *daily*, why don't you just step back, say, 90 days, rather than trying to step back 3 months and wrestle with ragged month-ends? Or is there some unexamined requirement?

Comment: @Walerian, also, in your last table (which I don't completely understand), there seems to be a contradiction in what I previously understood the logic to be: you have 30th Apr including 29th Feb, but logically 29th Feb would also have been included in the 29th April batch job (because it is a direct match on the monthday), I had understood that where the base monthday is higher than the last monthday a target month, `NULL` should be selected, not (as here) the final day of the month, because that will lead to certain past dates being included twice in successive daily batch jobs.

Comment: You're right, 29th Feb shouldn't be there - my mistake. I don't understand what you mean by stepping back 90 days - could you be more precise?

Comment: @Walerian, fair one. But as I say, why don't you just step back a fixed number of days or weeks? For example, if you want all historical data to be refreshed on a 30 day cycle, just step back 30, 60, 90, 120, etc. days. It won't align with months, but it doesn't align anyway because you're handling certain monthdays "ahead of time" when the base month is a short one. I'm sorry to keep picking at information you don't want to provide, but my intuition is that this approach is complex, ill-advised, and difficult to reason about unless an iron justification is present.

Comment: I mean that instead of stepping back to the same monthday X months ago, and having to tackle the problem of ragged month lengths, simply step back X days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest a slight simplification Walerian?

```
SELECT 
    *

FROM 
    orders

WHERE 
    (
        DAYOFMONTH(created_at) = DAYOFMONTH( NOW() ) --monthdays that match
    )
    OR
    (
        (  DAYOFMONTH(  LAST_DAY( NOW() )  ) = DAYOFMONTH( NOW() )  ) --base date is end of month
        AND
        (  DAYOFMONTH(created_at) > DAYOFMONTH( NOW() )  ) --target monthdays are beyond base monthday
    )
```

Incidentally I don't have a MySQL environment, so I'm just taking it on trust that these are the correct functions in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use DAYOFMONTH() function to compare the day of the NOW() and the created_at.
Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS
WHERE (DAYOFMONTH(NOW() < LAST_DAY(NOW()) -- if not last day of month 
        AND DAYOFMONTH(created_at) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW())
OR (LAST_DAY(NOW()) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) -- if last day of month
     AND DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH(created_at) AND LAST_DAY(created_at)) --
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't cover the edge cases of the last day of month.

Comment: @Walerian did you look at the modifications above? Does it address all edge cases now?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does't work. First of all, `LAST_DAY(date)` returns whole date, so it should have been `DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(date))`. But that didn't help either. But you guided me in a right direction, so I'm upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [suresubs's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9125296/suresubs) answer, I figured out how the query should look like.

```
SELECT * FROM orders
-- (1)
WHERE (DAYOFMONTH(NOW) < DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(NOW()))
  AND DAYOFMONTH(created_at) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()))
-- (2)
OR (DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(NOW())) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW())
  AND DAYOFMONTH(created_at) BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(created_at)));
```

It's using [`DAYOFMONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) and [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) functions and it's divided into two cases:

1. Today is **not** the last day of current month.
2. Today is the last day of current month.